# Bug in Android C++/C debugger, incorrect argument values

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, lldb

I have recently encountered a really weird problem while debugging C/C++ application in Android Studio.

I am using `Android Studio 3.0`

Here is my `JNI Call`

```
JNIEXPORT jshortArray JNICALL
Java_net_crosp_android_library_ecgaudioprocessor_EcgSignalProcessorDemodulator_demodulate(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jshortArray readBuffer_) {

    /* get size of the array */
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(readBuffer_);
    int sample_rate = 44100;
    int kd = 12;
    SignalConfiguration signal_cfg = {sample_rate, kd, 1700, sample_rate, sample_rate / kd, 200};
    ECGFMDemodulator *ecg_fm_demodulator = new ECGFMDemodulator();
    ecg_fm_demodulator->set_cfg(signal_cfg);
    ECGFMDemodulator *ecg_fm_demodulator2 = new ECGFMDemodulator(signal_cfg);

    /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
    jshort *body = env->GetShortArrayElements(readBuffer_, JNI_FALSE);

    env->ReleaseShortArrayElements(readBuffer_, body, JNI_COMMIT);
    return readBuffer_;
}
```

Class `ECGFMDemodulator`

```
class ECGFMDemodulator {
private:
    SignalConfiguration m_signal_configuration_;
public:

    ECGFMDemodulator(SignalConfiguration configuration);

    void set_cfg(SignalConfiguration param);
};
```

And implementation

```
ECGFMDemodulator::ECGFMDemodulator(SignalConfiguration configuration) {
    this->m_signal_configuration_ = configuration;
    std::cout.rdbuf(new Androidbuf);
    // Print values
    std::cout << "------ VALUES OF CONFIGURATION --------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sample rate : " << this->m_signal_configuration_.sample_rate << std::endl;
    std::cout << "KD : " << this->m_signal_configuration_.kd << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FC : " << this->m_signal_configuration_.fc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FS : " << this->m_signal_configuration_.fs << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FS2 : " << this->m_signal_configuration_.fs2 << std::endl;
    delete std::cout.rdbuf(0);
    this->init_filters();
}

void ECGFMDemodulator::set_cfg(SignalConfiguration param) {
    this->m_signal_configuration_ = param;
}
```

I am creating an object like that

```
int sample_rate = 44100;
int kd = 12;
SignalConfiguration signal_cfg = {sample_rate, kd, 1700, sample_rate, sample_rate / kd, 200};
ECGFMDemodulator *ecg_fm_demodulator = new ECGFMDemodulator();
ecg_fm_demodulator->set_cfg(signal_cfg);
ECGFMDemodulator *ecg_fm_demodulator2 = new ECGFMDemodulator(signal_cfg);
```

And while debugging I got interesting results

1. Creating `signal_cfg`, as you can see values are valid

[image]

2. Watching values in the constructor, as you can see values are random

[image]

3. After creating this object, values are correct and printed to console with valid values. However in debugger they are still garbage.

> ```
> I/std: ------ VALUES OF CONFIGURATION --------
> I/std: Sample rate : 44100
> I/std: KD : 12
> I/std: FC : 1700
> I/std: FS : 44100
> I/std: FS2 : 3675
> ```

[image]

I have also tried to use `lldb` but got the same values, that are not valid. I've also tried to pass by reference, but got the same result.

```
(lldb) frame variable
(ECGFMDemodulator *) this = 0xb7688d29
(SignalConfiguration) param = (sample_rate = -1217884423, kd = -1204349992, fc = -1217887850, fs = -1982518100, fs2 = -1983635321, delay = 36)
```

What is wrong with debugger, I am not able to debug my program, because I am not sure that values being displayed are valid.

Does anyone experiencing similar problems ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization?  Debuggers often have problems with the value of variables in optimized code (because the values are stored in registers, not in memory).

Comment: @MartinBonner, what do you mean by optimization ?