# android studio lldb display std::vector's incorrect value

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface, stdvector, lldb

I debug JNI std:: vector code in the android studio, LLDB display std:: vector's element incorrect value, but the std:: vector memory is correct. the effect is below image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BVgF.png

develop environment:
MacBook Pro 10.12.6
Android Studio:3.1.1
LLDB: 3.1
The "hello-libs" demo is one of google git https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk.git

Similar problems link:[Bug in Android C++/C debugger, incorrect argument values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47389139/bug-in-android-c-c-debugger-incorrect-argument-values)